# cursor.getType() and CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException exception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, gettype

There is a thing that I can not understand about `Cursor.getType()`, can anyone explain why do I get this stupid exception when I want to get columns type if cursor has no record but there are columns? I mean, if cursor has record there is no problem, I can use `getType` method to get columns type without any problem but if there is no any record it throws this exception out.

The question is why must I need records to get columns type? Why just knowing columns name is not enough to get types of it? Is this ridiculous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because SQLite uses dynamic typing:

> Most SQL database engines (every SQL database engine other than
>   SQLite, as far as we know) uses static, rigid typing. With static
>   typing, the datatype of a value is determined by its container - the
>   particular column in which the value is stored.
>
> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the
>   datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its
>   container.

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

So no value, no data type.