# Cursor#getType() is Index Out Of Bounds

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Basically I have this:

```
Cursor cur = ...
for (int i = 0; i < cur.getColumnCount(); i++) {
     String name = cur.getColumnName(i);
     Log.d("dao",name);
     int type = cur.getType(i);
```

... and getting in the `getType()` call the above Exception. 
The column name is logged correct.

> ERROR AndroidRuntime  Caused by:
>   android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested,
>   with a size of 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [cursor.getType() and CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133784/cursor-gettype-and-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the SQLite database, that uses dynamic typing. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133784/cursor-gettype-and-cursorindexoutofboundsexception-exception) too.
Why don't you use:

```
Cursor cur = ...

if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String name = cur.getColumnName(i);
        int type = cur.getType(i);
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you ask only for the type, if a row exist.

If you need the column type independently of any results, you might use:

```
String tableName = "...";
Cursor cursor = rawQuery("pragma table_info(" +tableName +")");
String type = getString(0);
String name = getString(1);
```

Hope this helps ... Cheers!

Comment: I really did the tests, but I didn't post it. There was a bug in my Cursor tests. Anyway, thank you for explaination.